# Can't play sound from Java on Orange Pi Ubuntu server

Tags: java, ubuntu, audio

Sound works fine when I do test:

> aplay -D hw:1,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/audio.wav

However when I try to `getSourceDataLine` and then open it, I am getting the exception:

javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian not supported.
at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:484)
at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:115)
at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:357)
at photoorganizer.formats.M4A$MP4Player.playLoop(M4A.java:204)
at photoorganizer.formats.SimpleMediaFormat$SimpleMediaPlayer.run(SimpleMediaFormat.java:323)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

There is the code snippet:

```
//create audio format
fmt = new AudioFormat(track.getSampleRate(), track.getSampleSize(), track.getChannelCount(), true, true);
line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(fmt);
line.open();
line.start();
```

I use Oracle JVM 17.7. Linux details:

> NAME="Ubuntu"
> VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
> ID=ubuntu
> ID_LIKE=debian
> PRETTY_NAME="Orange Pi 1.1.6 Focal"
> VERSION_ID="20.04"
> HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
> SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
> PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
> VERSION_CODENAME=focal
> UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

JVM details:

> java.vm.specification.vendor  Oracle Corporation
> java.specification.name   Java Platform API Specification
> sun.management.compiler   HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
> java.runtime.version  17.0.7+8-LTS-224